# Running load tests via Jenkins on a slave EC2 instance that starts and stops with the build

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, load-testing

Ideally, we'd like to run load tests on an EC2 Jenkins slave that starts and stops with our build.

Are there any tools out there (without writing our own plugins) that currently solve this?

I've come across [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin), but it seems to only be triggered based on the load of Jenkins in general, and not tied to a build.

This configuration is environment specific, and not project specific, so I would prefer to keep this maintained within Jenkins instead of within Maven and the project itself. Although, I'm open to suggestions in that realm.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [WebLOAD Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebLOAD+Plugin), it executes [RadView's WebLOAD](http://radview.com) load testing tool, triggered by Jenkins. WebLOAD itself can launch EC2 cloud machines as needed, if that's what you need.